# React Devtools unavailable in Redux examples

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm following the [Redux examples](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples) on Github. After `npm install` and `npm start` the Counter example, the app runs on localhost:3000. All is well except for the fact that React DevTools is stuck in "Connecting to React..." after opening Chrome devtools and navigating to the React tab (it's the React Devtools Chrome extension I'm using). Tweaking the code to enable Redux Devtools works fine. How can I get React Devtools working with these examples?

[image: React Devtools Connecting...]
[image: Redux Devtools working okay]

----- Update 2016-05-22 ------

After updating node to latest stable (v6.2.0) and reinstalling node modules, React devtools are available :)

Comment: It seems a bit flaky, but generally it does work for me.

Comment: Thanks @MattZeunert yeah it generally works fine, its just this set of examples it's not playing nice with. Did you find Devtools work on your setup with this repo?

Comment: Yes, I installed the Redux examples and ran them locally. It might be worth checking you have the latest version of the repo.

Comment: @MattZeunert took your advise on having the latest version...updated node to latest stable v6.2.0, reinstalled node modules and React devtools are working. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction buddy.